# Screenshot for nokia theme

Tags: php, themes, s60

How can i create several screenshots (desktop, menu) from nokia theme for s60 platform in sis formt using lamp?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do, where you want to take screenshots from (the mobile? a mobile app?), what the SIS format is, what the LAMP stack has to do with it, and whether this is intended to be a one-time thing for you at home, or an on-line service you want to program (which is important info to get the right answer.)

Comment: ok, i want to create a gallery of themes for nokia phones. I'm need to upload themes to my site in administration subsystem. When uploading theme i'm need to create screenshot of theme to display it later in themes gallery. in s40 themes are just archive of images and xml and i can parse it to create screens, but in s60 there are different theme format, in my mind its binary

Comment: what does PHP has to do with that. Please explain your question more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have knowledge of all those theme formats, then write code to read the theme files to render images. It'll be hard work, but there is no out-of-the-box PHP solution for that and your question is too general I think. It might be easier to make screenshots manually and upload them together with the theme files.